# JAR files for AWS S3 File Download

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What are the required jar files for upload/download files from AWS S3 bucket for WEB Application. I tried with below Jar files but still not able to succeed. 
`aws-java-sdk-1.10.26
aws-java-sdk-1.10.26-javadoc
aws-java-sdk-1.10.26-sources
aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.10.26
apache-httpcomponents-httpcore
apache-httpcomponents-httpclient
com.fasterxml.jackson.core
jackson-databind-2.2.3
jackson-annotations-2.2.3
httpclient-4.2`

Help me to add only the required JAR files. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download the AWS Java SDK (pre packed / zip form). Include all the jars from lib and third-party.

Answer (score 2):

You should get it as a maven depencendy as its MUCH easier that way, but if you have time you can also check the jar's on here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum dependency list for amazon s3 sdk basic operations such as 
upload or download.

The minimum dependencies are as follows:-

- aws-java-sdk-1.6.7
- commons-codec-1.3
- commons-logging-1.1.1
- httpclient-4.2.3
- httpcore-4.2
- jackson-databind-2.1.1
- jackson-core-2.1.1
- jackson-annotations-2.1.1

Note that aws-java-sdk-1.6.7 requires **commons-codec-1.3.jar**. If you do not include this particular version, then aws might not warn you of internal errors but would silently skip exceptions thereby giving faulty results.

Also, you should use **joda-time-2.8.1.jar** for authentication and aws date/time sync purposes!

In additon to these I also include apache commons-io for optimized download methods/file copy utilities etc. (It's a great combo and makes your file download work a lot easier)